# instantiating parameterized class

Tags: java, generics, parameterized-constructor

Just wondering if this is the right way to do it. I want to construct instances of my parametrized class where one of the instance variables is a generic type. The code below works but I get a lot of warnings in the main method "SomeObject is a raw type. References to generic type SomeObject should be parameterized".

```
public class SomeObject<T> {

    private String description;

    private T value;


    public SomeObject(String description, T value) {
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    }



public static void main(String args[]){

    List <SomeObject> objectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

    objectList.add(new SomeObject("Object 1: ", true));
    objectList.add(new SomeObject("Object 2: ", 888.00));
    objectList.add(new SomeObject("Object 3: ", "another object"));
    objectList.add(new SomeObject("Object 4: ", '4'));

    for (SomeObject object : objectList){
    System.out.println(object.getDescription() + object.getValue());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? You should actually use your generics.

Comment: should it be `new SomeObject()` instead of `new Object()`?

Comment: Try parameterizing the object creation like you have done for arraylist

Comment: "should it be new SomeObject() instead of new Object()?  " Yes it should. I edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Just a side note: in Java 7 and later, you can often omit the type in the second set of angle brackets, and let it be inferred. It is called the diamond operator.

Comment: see https://ideone.com/iXQZwj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code below works but I get a lot of warnings in the main method
>   "Object is a raw type. References to generic type Object should be
>   parameterized".

the warning is because you haven't specified the type arguments when constructing the `SomeObject`. ie.

it should be:

```
List<SomeObject<?>> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
objectList.add(new SomeObject<Boolean>("Object 1: ", true));
objectList.add(new SomeObject<Double>("Object 2: ", 888.00));
objectList.add(new SomeObject<String>("Object 3: ", "another object"));
objectList.add(new SomeObject<Character>("Object 4: ", '4'));
```

Comment: Can you add the declaration of objectList with type to complete your answer?

Comment: @RC. sure thing.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a `SomeObject` without a type argument (the part in the square brackets), that is called a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), and it's the same as using the erasure of `SomeObject`. (Basically, the erasure means it's non-generic.)

You also need to provide a type argument to the `SomeObject` part of the `List`. Here I've used a wildcard, which means the list can hold any type of `SomeObject`, but once we put a `SomeObject` in to the list we don't know what their original type argument was anymore:

```
List<SomeObject<?>> objectList = new ArrayList<SomeObject<?>>();

objectList.add(new SomeObject<Boolean>("Object 1: ", true));
objectList.add(new SomeObject<Double>("Object 2: ", 888.00));
objectList.add(new SomeObject<String>("Object 3: ", "another object"));
objectList.add(new SomeObject<Character>("Object 4: ", '4'));

for (SomeObject<?> object : objectList) {
    ...;
}
```